# Using matplotlib for Gaussian

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

so I am trying to plot a histogram of my data and I seem to be a little confused here. I am using matplotlib in python. Here is the code from their website:

```
 mu = 100 #mean
sigma = 15 #std deviation
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
```

I am confused as to what the x -axis should be for my use. I have calculated the standard deviation and the mean but, I am uncertain if I should replace the np.random.randn(10000) with the actual data or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your data into `x` variable, that's all. You do not need to compute mean or variance.